# keep a bluetooth connection when changing UIViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, core-location, cbperipheral

I put my peripheral delegate's methods in my 2 UIViewController but when I enter in the second I lose my connection and it connect again. 
What i want is simple, it is to keep the connection with the sames CBPeripheralManager and CBMUtableCharacteristic. There is any solution ?

Thank you

Comment: Bring the example of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for simple app, for example, you can create `CBPeripheralManager` in appDelegate,

but right way is make dedicated object for entire app (singleton) that will be CBPeripheralManager delegate and provide data to all your interface controllers

Comment: Thank you, it is what I thought. Do you have an exemple of how to use a singleton for this kind of apps ?

Comment: just move all delegate methods to new class and write init, then, if something be not clean to you post code to question